# Change default color of SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, theme

I would need to change green on the site collection from green to another shade of green.

We're using SPFx solution on the site.

E.g. this is the default color from default theme right now:

[image]

It's `#8CBF26` and I would need it to be `#96E83C`.

How can I achieve this? What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by utilising custom themes. I would use the theme generator tool to create a custom theme and then upload it using PowerShell (other APIs/methods are available). For more information, take a look at the documentation linked below:

[SharePoint site theming](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview)

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-theme-colors-in-your-customizations

To do this in your SPFx solution you can use a theme token. For ex.

This:

```
.button {
    background-color: #8CBF26;
}
```

Would become:

```
.button {
    background-color: "[theme: themePrimary, default: #96E83C]";
}
```

`themePrimary` is the theme token. SharePoint Framework uses the value specified by using the `default` parameter. The link above will guide you further, test and let me know if this works.